# How to add Custom marker icon to Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, joomla, components, joomla1.5

I am using this extension of joomla for google map http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions ... /maps/5248. But unable to change the placemark icon everytime when I add new marker.

I want the functionality like My map in google for the placemark.

Can anyone know how to do it with this extention or any alternative for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which component are you using? There are all kinds of map extensions you can use that will have what you need. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/maps

Comment: i download component from below link:-http://mapdemo.110mb.com/content/view/2/17/   .I want the functionality like My map in google for the placemark.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy

Once you have installed the plugin on your website on the right hand side you will see a lot of options

In the Parameter that says URL to Icon:  find the image/gif/jpeg file and select it here then you have to make a few changes to the size, width etc, if you need to.  If you get stuck go to 
http://tech.reumer.net/Google-Maps/Demo-Google-Maps-V3/custom-animated-icon.html

If you still have problems email the administrator they are excellent !!